# Gallery and Form View on the same screen

Tags: office365, screen, powerapps

I want to have a item list (SP list based) as a gallery on the left side of a screen. When I click on one item the item should show in total of the richt side. Is there a connection between the gallery and a inserted Form View that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this and many caveats (types of controls in the app, should user be able to edit form, etc.).

**Here is the gist:**

1. Add a Gallery to the left side of the screen
2. `OnSelect` of an icon in the Gallery; `Set(varSelectedItem, ThisItem)`

- This will save the entire record as a variable

3. Add a Form to the right side of the screen
4. Set the Form `DataSource` property to your Sharepoint list
5. Set the Form `Item` proptery to `varSelectedRecord`

**In action, it looks like this:**
(NOTE: I'm using a Collection rather than Sharepoint List, but same concept)

[image]